# Replacing redundant key names across all dictionaries in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key

How can I replace redundant keys in a nested dictionary?

For instance, if I have the following nested loop:

```
nested_dict = { 
'dict1': {'key_As': 'value_A', 'key_B': 'value_B', 'key_C': 'value_C', 'key_D': 'value_D'}, 
'dict2': {'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_B': 'value_B', 'key_C': 'value_C', 'key_D': 'value_D'}, 
'dict3': {'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_Bs': 'value_B', 'key_C': 'value_C', 'key_D': 'value_D'},
...
'dictN': {'key_As': 'value_A', 'key_Bs': 'value_B', 'key_C': 'value_C', 'key_D': 'value_D'}
}
```

I would like to replace all of the 'key_As' with 'Key_A' and all of the 'Key_Bs' with 'Key_B'?

For a standalaone dictionary, I would do the following:

```
dictionary['key_A'] = dictionary.pop('key_As')
```

But I do not know how to extend this to a huge nested dictionary.

Thank you

Comment: "Computationally elegant" seems pretty unclear and subjective to me. What do you mean by this? What sort of performance/efficiency problems are you having with a current solution and how much improvement do you need? Can you describe and show what you've tried to do to solve the problem as a [mcve]? You mention a loop, but I only see a dictionary. Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
old_new = {'key_As': 'key_A', 'key_Bs': 'key_B'}
old_keys = set(old_new)    

for value_dict in nested_dict.values():
    for old_key in set(value_dict) & old_keys:
        value_dict[old_new[old_key]] = value_dict.pop(old_key)
```

I've done a performance test using my approach and @Krrr's approach:

```
import timeit

setup = """
nested_dict = {f'dict1_{d}' : {'key_As': 'value_A', 'key_B': 'value_B', 'key_C': 'value_C', 'key_D': 'value_D'} for d in range(n)}
nested_dict.update({ f'dict2_{d}' : {'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_B': 'value_B', 'key_C': 'value_C', 'key_D': 'value_D'} for d in range(n)})
nested_dict.update({ f'dict3_{d}' : {'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_Bs': 'value_B', 'key_C': 'value_C', 'key_D': 'value_D'} for d in range(n)})

def test_rusu():
    old_new = {'key_As': 'key_A', 'key_Bs': 'key_B'}
    old_keys = set(old_new)    

    for value_dict in nested_dict.values():
        for old_key in set(value_dict) & old_keys:
            value_dict[old_new[old_key]] = value_dict.pop(old_key)

def test_Krrr():
    for i, d in nested_dict.items():
        nested_dict[i] = {{'key_As': 'key_A', 'key_Bs': 'key_B'}.get(k, k): v for k, v in d.items()}"""

data = {i : (timeit.timeit('test_rusu()', setup= f'n={i}\n' + setup, number=100),
             timeit.timeit('test_Krrr()', setup= f'n={i}\n' + setup, number=1000)) for i in (10, 100, 1_000, 10_000)}

pd.DataFrame({'Number of nested dicts': [3 * e for e in data.keys()], "rusu's time(Seconds)": [round(e[0], 4) for e in data.values()],
              "Krrr's time(seconds)": [round(e[1], 4) for e in data.values()]})
```

output:

[image]

or:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, d in nested_dict.items():
    nested_dict[i] = {{'key_As': 'key_A', 'key_Bs': 'key_B'}.get(k, k): v for k, v in d.items()}

nested_dict

{
  'dict1': {'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_B': 'value_B', 'key_C': 'value_C', 'key_D': 'value_D'}, 
  'dict2': {'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_B': 'value_B', 'key_C': 'value_C', 'key_D': 'value_D'}, 
  'dict3': {'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_B': 'value_B', 'key_C': 'value_C', 'key_D': 'value_D'}, 
  'dictN': {'key_A': 'value_A', 'key_B': 'value_B', 'key_C': 'value_C', 'key_D': 'value_D'}
}
```